# Recibir un mensaje WIN32 en una clase de C#

Tags: c#, windows

Lo que intento es enviar un mensaje WIN32 mediante

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
```

y recibirlo en mi clase estática Program, donde tengo el método `main()`.

Se que en un form se puede recibir mediante `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`, pero no se como hacerlo (o si se puede hacer) en una clase normal.

Comment: Tendrías que explicar un poco más lo que pretendes lograr. Porque en realidad esa función solo funciona si existe una ventana, lo que no pareces tener en tu caso, y típicamente solo tiene sentido si tienes algún UI. Pudiera ser que tengas que crear una ventana artificial solo para poder llamar a la función, pero no estoy seguro que sea la solución adecuada. Como te digo, tendría que entender mejor la intención detrás de lo que estás tratando de hacer.

Comment: Estaba intentando hacer que mi app fuera de una sola instancia. Si el usuario abre una segunda instancia se abre el form de la primera y la segunda se cierra, como explican acá http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html . Si tengo un form, pero se abre solo cuando el usuario oprime el ícono de las notificaciones. Ya estaba valorando eliminar la pregunta cdo encontré este método `Application.AddMessageFilter(msg_filter)`, implementando la interfaz `IMessageFilter` para rellenar `msg_filter`. Funciona bien, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible mediante `Application.AddMessageFilter(msg_filter)`.

Primero se implementa la interfaz `IMessageFilter`, aquí es donde se reciben los mensajes:

```
class MessageFilter:IMessageFilter {
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        if(m.Msg == mensaje_a_procesar) {
            //Aqui se realiza la acción
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Luego se utiliza para rellenar el parámetro de la función:

```
MessageFilter msg_filter = new MessageFilter();
Application.AddMessageFilter(msg_filter);
```